# Test if an EditText view has no error text set with Espresso on Android?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I know how to test if an error text is set in an `EditText`:

```
editText.check(matches(hasErrorText("")));
```

Now I want to test if an `EditText` has no error text set. I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
editText.check((matches(not(hasErrorText("")))));
```

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think it's possible that way, depending on what you want exactly, I would use a custom matcher:

```
public static Matcher<View> hasNoErrorText() {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, EditText>(EditText.class) {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has no error text: ");
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(EditText view) {
            return view.getError() == null;
        }
    };
}
```

This matcher can check if an EditText does not have any error text set, use it like this:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edittext), isDisplayed())).check(matches(hasNoErrorText()));
```